# Concatenation of a variant number of keys of a dictionary Python (recursion?)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, key, concatenation

Hello Stackoverlow members,

I'm trying to concatenate keys (string) on a hand, and values (list) on the other hand, of a dictionnary.

For your better understanding, here is what I have at the beginning:

```
dict = {'bk1':
            {'k11': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
             'k12': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']},
        'bk2':
            {'k21': ['d1', 'e1'],
             'k22': ['d2', 'e2'],
             'k23': ['d3', 'e3']},
        'bk3':
            {'k31': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
             'k32': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2']}
        }
```

And here is what I would like at the end:

```
newdict = {'k11_k21_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k11_k21_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
           'k11_k22_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k11_k22_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
           'k11_k23_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k11_k23_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
           'k12_k21_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k12_k21_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
           'k12_k22_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k12_k22_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
           'k12_k23_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
           'k12_k23_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2']}
```

I wish to do that with:

- a **variant** number of "big key" (bki), and for each bki, a **variant** number of key (kij).
- "Full combination" between "big keys". For example, I don't expect results like:

  ```
  {'k11_k23': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3']}
  ```

where the "bk3" is missed.

I tried with imbricated "for" loops but the number of loops is depending on the number of "big keys"...

Then, I felt that the problem could be solved with recursion (maybe?), but in spite of my research and my will to implement it, I failed.

Any help with "recursive or not" solution would be strongly appreciated.

Thank you,

Mat

---

Whoaa, what a reactivity!
Thanks a lot for all your quick answers, it works **perfect!**

Comment: Would Python's [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @jksnw in the comments, you can use `itertools.product` to do this:

```
import itertools

dct = {
    'bk1': {
        'k11': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
        'k12': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
    },
    'bk2':{
        'k21': ['d1', 'e1'],
        'k22': ['d2', 'e2'],
        'k23': ['d3', 'e3']
    },
    'bk3': {
        'k31': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
        'k32': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2']
    }
}

big_keys = dct.keys()
small_keys = (dct[big_key].keys() for big_key in big_keys)

res = {}
for keys_from_each in itertools.product(*small_keys):
    key = "_".join(keys_from_each)

    value = []
    for big_key, small_key in zip(big_keys, keys_from_each):
        value.extend(dct[big_key][small_key])

    res[key] = value
```

So that:

```
>>> res

{'k11_k21_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k11_k21_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 'k11_k22_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k11_k22_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 'k11_k23_k31': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k11_k23_k32': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 'k12_k21_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k12_k21_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 'k12_k22_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k12_k22_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'],
 'k12_k23_k31': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1'],
 'k12_k23_k32': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2']}
```

Here, `itertools.product` is used to get a list of the "small keys" that we take from each block:

```
>>> big_keys = dct.keys()
>>> small_keys = (dct[big_key].keys() for big_key in big_keys)
>>> list(itertools.product(*small_keys))

[('k12', 'k22', 'k31'),
 ('k12', 'k22', 'k32'),
 ('k12', 'k23', 'k31'),
 ('k12', 'k23', 'k32'),
 ('k12', 'k21', 'k31'),
 ('k12', 'k21', 'k32'),
 ('k11', 'k22', 'k31'),
 ('k11', 'k22', 'k32'),
 ('k11', 'k23', 'k31'),
 ('k11', 'k23', 'k32'),
 ('k11', 'k21', 'k31'),
 ('k11', 'k21', 'k32')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product`, and `reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,i)` to flatten your nested lists , also do not use `dict` or other python built-in types name or keywords as your variables name (i used `d`) :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> v=[i.values() for i in d.values()]
>>> v=[reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,i) for i in product(*v)]
>>> k=[i.keys() for i in d.values()]
>>> k=['_'.join(i) for i in product(*k)]
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(k,v)}
{'k31_k12_k22': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'], 
 'k32_k12_k21': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1'],         
 'k31_k11_k22': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2'], 
 'k31_k12_k23': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3'], 
 'k32_k12_k22': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'], 
 'k31_k12_k21': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1'], 
 'k32_k11_k23': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3'], 
 'k32_k12_k23': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd3', 'e3'], 
 'k31_k11_k21': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], 
 'k31_k11_k23': ['f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3', 'e3'], 
 'k32_k11_k21': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], 
 'k32_k11_k22': ['f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2']}
```

Comment: Very helpful the answer, just that maybe it should be included the imports. I know that it is made on console but I was trying the code to understand what does it does and maybe it can confuse someone. 

from itertools import product
import functools

Comment: @in python 3 `reduce` is not a built-in function,but its in `functools` module! if you are in 3 you need to use it!

Comment: @RicardoBurillo did you imported `product`?

Comment: yes yes I have imported all necessary and it works. It was just that I got errors because of the import, nothing more. I have voted up your answer, it was just to consider